# Firebase 'OR' condition on single field

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my application the main entity is threads, I mean sneakers, jackets, t-shorts and so on.

This is firebase db:

[image]

I have logic witch fetch threads by 'threadTypes'. In my app there're 3 types - outwear, footwear and accessory.
That is code:

```
extension GoodsViewController {

    func fetchThreads(completion: @escaping (Swift.Void) -> Swift.Void) {

        self.ref
            .child("threads")
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                for rest in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                    guard let restDict = rest.value as? [String: Any] else { continue }
                    let thread = Thread()
                    thread.setValuesForKeys(restDict)

                    if Search.searchFilters.stuffTypes.isEmpty {
                        self.threads.append(thread)
                    }
                    else {
                        if let threadType = thread.threadType {
                            if Search.searchFilters.stuffTypes.contains(threadType) {
                                self.threads.append(thread)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                completion()
            })
    }
}
```

*self.threads* - is variable which is used as table view datasource.

*Search.searchFilters.stuffTypes* - array which contains types for search.

As you see I fetch all threads and then check if current thread type contains in *Search.searchFilters.stuffTypes* array.

My question is - is it possible to perform this checking before I fetch all threads?
In C# it should be something like that -

```
threads.Where(t => Search.searchFilters.stuffTypes.Contains(t.threadType)
```

Comment: The question is a bit unclear; are you asking if you can query Firebase for all child nodes where threadType is *footwear* or *outerwear*? If so, could you just do two queries; one for footwear nodes and then a second query for outerwear nodes?

Comment: @Jay yep, you are totally right. I need to build a query where threadType either footwear or outwear.